# single-spa: redefine console.log for every microfront

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend, single-spa, zone.js

Let's assume I have several single-spa react microfrontend apps in my project, e.g. `Cart` and `Products`

I want to redefine `console.log`, `console.error`, etc. so that it had prefix with appropriate microfrontend app name:

- `console.log` invoked from `Cart` app: `[Cart]: some log info`
- `console.log` invoked from `Products` app: `[Products]: some log info`

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

I thought of zone.js, but the execution context is not being passed to component's children:

```
import type React from 'react';
import 'zone.js';

export const withLogger = (
  Component: React.ReactElement,
  regionName: string
): React.ReactElement =>
  Zone.current
    .fork({
      name: regionName
    })
    .run(() => {
      const consoleLogOG = console.log;
      window.console.log = (...args): void => {
        const newArgs = [`[${Zone.current.name}]`, ...args];
        consoleLogOG.apply(console, newArgs);
      };

      return Component;
    });
```

UPD: I want to create out of the box solution for about 20 microfronts, so I don't want to move from standard `console.log` to any custom logger. Ideally, I want to create some kind of a HOC which will redefine `console.log` for all of the calls within wrapper's subtree (execution context)

Comment: Uhm... obviously you can't change the global `console`, because the variable is indeed global, thus shared across microfrontends. I suppose you can't even replace  `console.log` with some custom log functions. Did you think about performing this replacement in webpack?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina yeah, `console.log` is shared between all of the microfronts, so the code I've provided is not perfect at all :)
But can webpack replacement of `console.log` solve this problem? Won't replaced function stay global across microfronts?

Comment: You could create your own logging utility and then try to pass in a different prefix as a variable / context in webpack depending on the app. I believe you can use [definePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) for this.
So then you can create a utility like: 

```const createLogger = (...args) => {
  console.log(`[${APP_PREFIX}]`, ...args);
};```

and import the utility as you need it `import logger from '@custom-logger';`

Comment: @HJEC We have about 20 microfronts in out team, some of them are legacy, some of them are still under development, so I don't want to force people to move from `console.log` to `logger`

Comment: You need consola on npm

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to make zone.js work in a situation where multiple microfrontends are being used with single-spa. This is because all of the microfrontends share the same environment and zone.js cannot handle this dynamic change.

one possible way would be to create a new function for logging that takes in a specific name for each microfrontend and includes it in the log message. Then, instead of using console.log, each microfrontend can use this new function for logging. This will help differentiate the logs from each microfrontend.

```
// Custom logging function
const customLog = (regionName, ...args) => {
  const newArgs = [`[${regionName}]:`, ...args];
  console.log.apply(console, newArgs);
};

// In your Cart microfront, you can use the custom log function like this:
customLog("Cart", "foo");

// In your Products microfront, you can use it like this:
customLog("Products", "foo");
```

Basically, instead of having all the log messages mixed together in a single file, we can organize them into separate files for each microfront. This will help us easily identify which microfront the log messages belong to by adding the region name before the message. It's like each microfront has their own little diary, but with their name on the cover so we know whose diary it is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But as I've said above in the comments, we have about 20 microfronts in out team, so I don't want to force people moving from `console.log` to `customLog`. I want to create the solution out of the box, not requiring people to refactor all of their code

Comment: then you can create a HOC that wraps each microfront before mounting it in single-spa.

Comment: How this HOC will redefine the `console.log`? The only way I can come up with is redefining the `window.console` object, but this object is general for all microfronts

Comment: it redefines the console.log by creating a new function that adds a prefix with the appropriate region name before calling the original console.log function. It does not redefine the window.console object, instead it provides a new function to the wrapped component via the customLog prop.

Comment: Could you provide the usage example of customLog provided to children pls

Comment: @Volok you can check another answer with that

Answer (score 0):

```
// HOC that wraps each microfront
const withLogger = (Component, regionName) => {
  const log = console.log;

  return (props) => {
    return <Component {...props} customLog={(...args) => log(`[${regionName}]:`, ...args)} />
  };
};

// using the HOC in a microfront app
const App = (props) => {
  const { customLog } = props;

  // This customLog prop will now be available and can be used
  customLog("foo");

  // other code
};

export default withLogger(App, "Products"); // App will now be wrapped with the HOC and have access to the customLog prop with the appropriate region name.
```

note: you have to consider how to handle asynchronous functions and error logging in a similar way. thoroughly test